# TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript

что за ошибка это, я понял, что не может вызывать класс, как функцию **TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function**, но что это означает? вот строка кода, которая вылетает в консоли, я так понимаю это встроенная функция от бабеля, на что она ругается я не понимаю.
`function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }`

скриншот ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сама ошибка вылезает, когда я пытаюсь передать селекторы классов от формы в экземпляр класса PoupWithForm

```
export default class PopupWithForm extends Popup {
  constructor (selectorPopup, selectorForm, handleFormSubmit) {
    super(selectorPopup);
    this._selectorForm = this._selectorPopup.querySelector(selectorForm)
    this._handleFormSubmit = handleFormSubmit;
  };
/* Получение значений из полей ввода */
  _getInputValues() {
    this._inputList = this._selectorPopup.querySelectorAll('.popup__input');
    console.log(this._inputList)
    this._newInputValues = {};
    this._inputList.forEach((inputElement) => {
      this._newInputValues[inputElement.name] = inputElement.value
    });
    return this._newInputValues
  };
/* Сброс значений полей ввода */
  resetForm() {
    this._selectorForm.reset();
  };
/* Добавление сброса формы в родительский метод закрытия модального окна*/
  closePopup() {
    super.closePopup(); 
    this.resetForm();
  };
/* Установка слушателей */
  setEventListeners() {
    super.setEventListeners();
    this._selectorForm.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
      evt.preventDefault();
      this._handleFormSubmit(this._getInputValues());
      this.closePopup();
    });
  }
};

/* ФОРМА ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ АВТАРА */

const popupUserAvatar = PopupWithForm(
  '.popup_type_user-avatar',
  '.popup__input-container_type_user-avatar',
  //handleFormUserAvatarSubmit
);

popupUserAvatar.setEventListeners();

changeProfileAvatarButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popupUserAvatar.openPopup();
});
```

Comment: Вы тут `new` забыли `const popupUserAvatar = new PopupWithForm(...)`

Comment: вот блин, пол дня просидел и не мог понять в чем дело ), спасибо